# Print with gnuplot from bash script

Tags: bash, gnuplot

I have a bash script that performs several operations and results in a text file like this:

```
1 34501.75262 bps
2 40505.58495 bps
3 190647.48201 bps
4 39468.40808 bps
5 241584.85273 bps
```

I'm trying to graph the contents of a txt file using gnuplot calling it from a bash script, but it has not worked for me. The command that I used in the gnuplot console that works and prints what I want is:

```
plot "Throughputrx.txt" using 1:2 title 'Throughput en RX' with lines
```

In the bash script I use the command:

```
gnuplot -e "plot "Throughputrx.txt" using 1:2 title 'Throughput en RX' with lines"
```

The error that shows me is:

```
line 0: undefined variable: Throughputrx
```

I tried escaping the quotes but when I do that it does not show an error but the graph of gnuplot does not appear.

Answer (score 0):

It's almost right. If you want to nest double quotes, you have to escape the inner ones:

```
gnuplot -e "plot \"Throughputrx.txt\" using 1:2 title 'Throughput en RX' with lines"
```

Or you can single quote the inner terms:

```
gnuplot -e "plot 'Throughputrx.txt' using 1:2 title 'Throughput en RX' with lines"
```

Comment: W, I had tried the two options that you indicate me, but when executing the script I do not get anything, neither an error message nor the desired graph.

Comment: @AndresAndrade If I set my gnuplot terminal to `dumb`, I get the output. Is the problem that your gnuplot window disappears immediately, as addressed in [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/257679/how-to-keep-gnuplot-x11-graph-window-open-until-manually-closed)? Do you get any message about a missing termianl?

Comment: W, I have looked for information about positioning my graphic in the center of my screen but I have not found much, if you have some information I would appreciate it.